# Release definition to publish nuget packages for multiple artifacts

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, artifact

I have a VSTS release definition that I want to use for publishing nuget packages for multiple artifacts. The artifacts for the different nuget packages are supplied to the release definition from different build definitions. Only artifacts from the build that triggered the release shall be downloaded and published. The pipeline is setup according to the picture below.

[image: Release definition]

That is, when a build triggers a new release, only artifacts from that build should be published in the release. All artifacts from the other build definitions should be ignored since the version number on those nuget packages are not updated and will fail to push.

Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/mar-05-vsts#improve-release-times-by-partially-downloading-artifacts

And then on that same link see **Deploy selectively based on the artifact triggering a release**

It will basically explain VSTS new features. The first one is to specify what you want to download on a release phase. The second one is to add a custom condition on a phase to define if it should be executed.

So you could create two phases, one for each of your artifacts. Each phase would only download the corresponding artifact and only run if the custom conditional evaluates true, using the new release variable `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias`.

Note that this release variable is only present if the release is continuous deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up using the release variable `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias` in the path to desired Nuget package in the downloaded artifacts.